# geolocation.getCurrentPosition not accurate on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, geolocation

On the iPhone with the location service activated on Safari or Chrome, the location is not accurate (like 1-2 miles difference). It seems that it apparently doesn't use the GPS coords. How can I make it as accurate as possible on the iPhone?

```
const options = {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    maximumAge: 0
  };

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  success,
  error,
  options
);

success = (pos) => {
  console.log(pos);
}
```

Why isn't it using the exact GPS Coordinates on the iPhone with activated Location Service on Safari / Chrome?